# Will wiping an Android device wipe the system or only personal files?

Tags: factory-reset

I am unable to use my phone. It will hold a charge and die quickly. I will be receiving a new phone tomorrow. However, I want to wipe my phone for my personal benefit.

Will it wipe the system or just my personal files?

Comment: dban wipes everything.

Comment: @jikag - dban is designed for hard drives.  Wiping flash behind a controller is a more difficult proposition as the physical blocks on the chip don't have a 1:1 mapping with the virtual blocks everything on the other side of the controller sees.

Answer (score 0):

This weekend I did a factory reset on my Droid Incredible, asking it to wipe everything.  (The phone had been slowly turning into a brick and this was the solution.)  After it finished, there was still a lot of my personal information on it, not just in the memory card, but also in the main memory of the phone.  I had it expected it all to be gone.

If I were going to sell or give a phone away, I would first do the factory reset then hook it to my PC, change the USB connection type to disk drive, scour for personal info, overwriting and `rm`ing everything I could find.

Comment: What was left behind on the main memory (and where)?  That shouldn't happen except perhaps on the "internal SD" partition.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't keep track since my objective was to restore the phone and it is possible I mistook stuff on the memory card as being in main memory.  But it sure looked to me like there was stuff left.